# Windows Does not Prompt for Elevation when Changing Configuration of Product Using Add\Remove Programs

Tags: windows-installer

We have an MSI installer authored using InstallShield that exhibits the following behavior.

Running the setup bootstrapper prompts the user to run elevated.

Once the product is installed I can open the Add\Remove program list, right click on the product and select modify. The modification UI runs and I am able to select a feature for installation that was not initially installed.

When I click the 'Finish' button I expect to be prompted for elevation. But I am not. The feature will partially install e.g. file will be written to the 'Program Files' folder but certain custom actions fail (such as starting a windows service).

If I launch the modify sequence from an elevated command prompt using MsiExec.exe everything works fine.

I checked that 'Require Administrative Privileges' is set to 'yes' in the summary information stream and the bootstrapper is set to require Admin rights.

I have created a new empty installer project with what seems to be the same settings and it behaves correctly i.e it prompts for elevation when the 'Finish' button is clicked while modifying the product configuration.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you initially run the EXE, the manifest elevates the EXE which in turn elevates the msiexec client and server processes.  The entire MSI is being run with more permissions then are appropriate.  More on this in a moment.

When you perform an ARP Modify, Windows calls Msiexec directly bypassing the EXE.  Because the installer is installed on a per-machine basis it's already trusted (managed) by the windows installer so no UAC prompts are needed.   The client side (Install UI sequence)  will run without elevation and deferred no impersonation custom actions / standard actions in the server side (InstallExecuteSequence) will run in the system context.  It then returns to the UI sequence and exits when you click Finish.  There is no expectation to elevate.

Now, about those custom actions.  Since they are failing, this tells me you haven't authored them correctly.   You don't mention what tool you are using to create your MSI.  If it's a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project (.VDPROJ )  you should  be aware that Microsoft deprecated this tool in future versions of VS.   One of the many reasons they did this is that it fails to expose much of the custom action authoring switches (it encapsulates it as Install, Uninstall, Rollback, Commit )  and when it does so they are scheduled as Deferred with Impersonation  which is incorrect and would only work if setup.exe inappropriately eleveated the entire installer.

For more understanding please see: [Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

These are my educated guesses after years of working on many installers.  Only a thorough architecture / code review of your project could confirm my suspicions.

Comment: After reading your explanation I have a couple of questions. Firstly, why do you think my skeleton test install shows the UAC prompt during the ARP modify? What would cause it to behave differently from my production installer? Secondly, doesn't the fact that running the modify (via msiexec.exe) from an elevated command prompt show that the execute phase is not being executed with admin privileges when run directly from ARP list.

Comment: FYI, I am using InstallShield 2012 Spring from Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What project type are you using?  Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI?

Comment: I think I'd need to see your project and installation logfiles to give you an exact answer.  Also you shouldn't need custom actions to install services.